# Why class variable of type array can't be initialized after declaration, but can be initialized inside a method in Java?

Tags: java

For below code, it gives a compilation error:

```
public class Main {

    int[] array = new int[10];
    array[5] = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Whereas below code doesn't give compilation error, what's the difference in both?

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        array[5] = 10;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For code to be executed it must either be at the declaration of a variable, or inside a method. In your first example `new int[5]` is at the declaration of the instance variable, but `array[5] = 10;` is neither at the declaration nor in a method. In the second example both are in a method.

**note**: Arrays are zero based, `array[5]` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. The minimum index is 0, the maximum 4, making 5 entries.

Comment: Don't forget initialisation blocks.  Code can live there too.

Comment: Yes, the `static { }` is a special named (or actually unnamed) method, but it is still a method.

Comment: Not all initialisation blocks are static.  And they're not methods.

Comment: Thanks Rutte, I have updated the index to have 10 values.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
public class Main {

    int[] array = new int[10];
    {
        array[5] = 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

As to the question "why", the answer is - because Java Language Specification does not allow arbitrary statements directly in the class body.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not a declaration, but a statement:

```
array[5] = 10;
```

Java has no clue when to execute it as (unlike when it's inside a method) it doesn't belong to well-defined control flow.

If you want to declare *and* initialize your array at a time, you can go something like this:

```
int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
```

This initialize each and every element of your array.